# Truncate & reload recent data in SQL Server stored procedure - Only update part of table (allow older data to remain static & update new data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, truncate

I have a stored procedure that creates a table with A LOT of data. It truncates and reloads this data every day which means worse performance as time goes on. I only want to update and add data within in the past year, but still have the older data in the table.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. "Refresh" existing data from the past year
2. Add new records that were created since the last time the stored procedure was ran (daily)
3. Leave data older than 1 year as is - I want to see it but don't care if it gets updated because it is very unlikely to change at all & it is slowing things down (I think)

Will someone please help me? I'm a little stuck. My best idea is to store old data in a table and union it with the new data which doesn't seem like much of an improvement.

Example code of what is there right now below:

```
drop table if exists [TABLENAME];

select 
    blabla1,
    blabla2,
    blabla3
into
    [TABLENAME]
from 
    table1 t1
join 
    table2 t2 on t2.x = t1.x
left join 
    table3 t3 on t3.x = t1.x
```

Comment: what is your end goal? is this feeding a report? is the existing stored procedure dumping a history table from an application into your data warehouse? if you only want to update and add data within the past year then you can do an all-history dump one time and use EXIST clauses to add/update. create appropriate indexes to speed things up as well as updating statistics. without actually seeing your system, it's hard to speculate in-detail what will work best for you. hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: You need to identify columns in your target and source tables that tell you "the past year" and "records that were created since the last time the stored procedure was ran". Then you just write merge (or update/insert) logic to merge them.

Comment: Good indexing should make short work of this, but we have no context so cannot advise. The code you have given us is pretty vague, we don't know what the rest of the columns look like, we don't have current indexes

Comment: Thank you all! I got it figured out and am using merge. I'm wondering if I should use update/insert instead because I think that is a little faster, but merge seems like it eliminates headaches so may be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Refreshing, save the rows in a temp table and delete the data which is more than a year old from temp table. Then use the Merge Query where you can specify your target and Source(temp table). Here is the sample:

```
MERGE TargetTable AS Target
-- Keys on which you will uniquely match the rows in Target table
USING SourceTable<your temp table> AS Source ON Source.Id = Target.Id 

--Updating the Target rows with Source table rows
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET Target.Name = Source.Name,
            Target.Price = Source.Price

-- if rows not matched, insert a new row in table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN 
    INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, Price) 
    VALUES (Source.ProductID, Source.ProductName, Source.Price);
```

You can refer to https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/

Comment: Thank you!!! I am using this and it is perfect! I really like how simple it is to merge instead of trying all kinds of workarounds. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Merge is good, it removes the complexity of Upsert logic.